# Program is exitting 'while' loop even though conditions are not met

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Simple excercise im trying out. The block of code shown tests if Username is taken and the Password strength.

Program should exit 'while' loop if both the variables equal true:

(`while(boolUserCheck == false && boolPwdCheck == false){}`)

Program is exitting loop eventhough boolUserCheck == true and boolPwdCheck == false.
In my test, i create a Username that is free (ie. boolUserCheck = true) and i create a weak password (ie. boolPwdCheck = false).

NOTE: I haven't tried the case where boolUserCheck == false and boolPwdCheck == false because i haven't finished the program so im not actually storing the user data anywhere to check taken Usernames.

I've checked that i used equal operators(==) where needed and not assignment operator(=). I used AND condition because BOTH need to be TRUE to exit. Return values are what i expected and so they enter their respective 'if' statements.

```
while(boolUserCheck == false && boolPwdCheck == false){
    std::cout << "Username: "; gets(name);
    std::cout << "Password: "; gets(pwd);

    boolUserCheck = UserCheck(name);   // Function that checks if Username is free (returns true)
    if(boolUserCheck == false){
        std::cout << "Username taken."; std::cin.get();
    }
    else{
        boolPwdCheck = PwdCheck(pwd);   // Function that checks password strength (returns false)
        if(boolPwdCheck == false){      // Therefore enters the 'if' statement
            std::cout << "Password must contain upper and lower case and special characters: !@#$%^&*<>()";
        }
    }
    //   I added this to check the values, which are: true and false respectively
    //   And yet program exits while loop
    std::cout << "\nboolUserCheck: " << boolUserCheck << "\nboolPwdCheck: "  << boolPwdCheck;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: my rubber duck wants to know what happens to `cond1 == false && cond2 == false` when only one of them is true.

Comment: You claim that `while(boolUserCheck == false && boolPwdCheck == false)` will exit if both variables are true.   Not so.   The loop will exit if *either* of the variables are true  i.e. it will ONLY continue if both are `false`.

Comment: *"Program is exitting loop eventhough boolUserCheck == true and boolPwdCheck == false."* -- this would be a valid complaint if your loop read "while boolUserCheck == true and boolPwdCheck == false". However it does not.

Comment: You probably want to use `while(boolUserCheck == false || boolPwdCheck == false){` instead of exiting when one of these are not false

Comment: I suggest to draw a simple truth table with all possible cominations of `boolUserCheck` and `boolPwdCheck` and `boolUserCheck == false && boolPwdCheck == false`. There's only one combination were this condition is true and It's the one that you claim to have not tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

> I used AND condition because BOTH need to be TRUE to exit

TL;DR: Exiting condition is both need to be true, meaning the running condition must be that, but inverted to `boolUserChecked == false || boolPwdChecked == false`

---

## Here's the long way

Let's check all our possible combinations using your condition

| boolUserCheck | boolPwdCheck | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | false |
| true | false | false |
| false | true | false |
| false | false | true |

This states that the loop is only running if both are false, but the condition you're looking for is:

> both need to be true to exit

meaning inversely if either is false, you need to keep running.
That, in program logic, is: `boolUserChecked == true && boolPwdChecked == true` to exit and `!(boolUserChecked == true && boolPwdChecked == true)` to keep running.
The condition inside your while loop decides whether it should keep running, thus you need the latter of them.
Using arithmetic you can rewrite that, without going into too much detail, arriving at `boolUserChecked == false || boolPwdChecked == false`